# dnvm can't find latest version from nuget.org

Tags: macos, dnx

Going through the steps of setting up dnvm on OSX and I can't seem to get past the dnvm upgrade step as it's returning the error:

```
~$ dnvm upgrade
Determining latest version
Error: Could not find latest version from feed https://nuget.org/api/v2
```

I can install based off the unstable feed using -u however then I run into a whole new set of issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This actually is caused by dnvm not following a redirect to www.nuget.org (instead of without the www).  It is fixed with the following line:

```
export DNX_FEED=https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

The packages will be available soon:

https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm/issues/235

Comment: That's actually not the issue.  See my answer bellow

Comment: You are right. I just found that issue right after the Keynote. Thanks!